# openssh - add keys to agent when entered

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

Whenever I enter my password, in e.g `git`, `ssh`, I want it to be remembered.

So I have conifgured `ssh-agent`

I also added `AddKeysToAgent yes` to `~/.ssh/config`

If I run `ssh-add` now every thing is fine. But without it, it doesn't work (I have to enter my password everytime)

I know I could add `ssh-add` to an init script but that's not what I want since I don't need it every day.  I thought that's what `AddKeysToAgent yes` is for?

I start `ssh-agent` as a systemd service with `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/ssh-agent.socket`.

### update

For testing I removed the service and SSH_AUTH_SOCK. Rebooted and ran `eval $(ssh-agent)` then logged in `ssh pi@my-ip` entered password and did it again. Still the password prompt. So it doesn't seem to be an issue with systemd.

### update 2

Moving `AddKeysToAgent yes` to the first line fixed it with eval.

Comment: Is the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable in your environment and does it contain the pathname of a socket file that exists?

Comment: yeah that's the correct path, the socket also exists, otherwise I asume `ssh-add` wouldn't work?

Comment: so did you get it to work with systemd service?

Comment: jep. as a said in my answer there was an issue with the format of `~/.ssh/config`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok so the issue was the format of `~/.ssh/config`. It was

```
Host awesomehost.tld
    User user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
AddKeysToAgent yes
```

It needs to be either

```
Host awesomehost.tld
    User user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Host *
    AddKeysToAgent yes
```

or

```
AddKeysToAgent yes
Host awesomehost.tld
    User user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: thanks the `IdentifyFile` line was missing for me...

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to starting the systemd service, you potentially could add the following code to your shell startup script (such as ~/.bashrc):

```
if ! pgrep -u "$USER" ssh-agent > /dev/null; then
    ssh-agent > "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/ssh-agent.env"
fi
if [[ ! "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]]; then
    eval "$(<"$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/ssh-agent.env")"
fi
```

I have also struggled to get the `ssh-agent` going via the (user's) systemd service, the [relevant section](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys#Start_ssh-agent_with_systemd_user) of the [ssh-agent part](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys#ssh-agent) of the [ssh-keys article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys) on the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/) might be of help. The above method worked like a charm so I never had any reason to look for an alternative.

Hope this can be of help to you.

Comment: you could just `source` the `.env` file. No need to use `eval` and a command substitution. However, you may also want to check whether `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is set to something valid, and then handle the case when it is not (as when logging in from a remote system using `ssh`?)